# Django complex filter through ManyToManyField and ForeignKey

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-queryset, manytomanyfield

I have a number of database tabels that are connected via manytomany and foreign key fields.

```
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Bookings(models.Model):
    user = user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        blank=True, 
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Event(models.Model):
    bookings = models.ManyToManyField(
        Booking, 
        related_name="event_bookings", 
        blank=True)

class ScheduleManager(models.Manager):

    def for_user(self, user):
        """
        Returns a Schedule queryset for a given user object.
        Usage:
            user= User.objects.first()
            Schedule.objects.for_user(user)
        """
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        #need to extend this to return Schedule qs
        return qs


class Schedule(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    objects = ScheduleManager()
```

I would like to query the database to output a Schedule queryset for a given User object by calling Schedule.objects.for_user(User).

I have been playing with a combination of prefetch_related and select_related to no prevail.

I can get hold of the correct qs by using a bunch of chained queries and loops but its not the most elegant and I'm am hitting the db far too many times.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse through the fields by seperating them wih `__`.

You want to reach `User` from `Schedule`, the route is as follows:

Schedule --> Event --> Bookings --> User

So, if you're starting from a `Schedule`, you can filter on users by doing so:

```py
my_user = get_user_object().objects.get(pk=1)
user_schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(event__bookings__user=my_user)
```

So if you convert the above to fit in your function, you'll get this:

```py
class ScheduleManager(models.Manager):

    def for_user(self, user):
        """
        Returns a Schedule queryset for a given user object.
        Usage:
            user= User.objects.first()
            Schedule.objects.for_user(user)
        """
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        qs = qs.filter(event__bookings__user=user)
        return qs
```